# python looping index

Tags: python, loops, indexing, music-notation

I am trying to write a program for getting the notes of a musical scale. This is what I've got up to now but it seems ridiculously complicated!! what am I missing? Is it supposed to be like that?

```
notes = [ "c", "c#", "d", "d#", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#", "a", "a#", "b" ]
major = [2,2,1,2,2,2] # semitone steps
root  = "f"
root_i= notes.index(root)

index = [root_i+i for i in [sum(major[:y]) for y in range(len(major)+1)]]
scale = [notes[i] if i < len(notes) else notes[i-len(notes)] for i in index]
```

I just need to increment the `root_i` by each "step" in `major` and restart when i reach the end of `notes`...

Thanks.

Comment: *I am trying to write a program for printing the notes of a musical scale* - I cannot see any `print` in your example. What output do you expect?

Comment: sorry, I'll edit. The outcome is correct, but it seems a bit overkill.. does it not?

Comment: You can use `major = [2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11]` to avoid `sum`

Comment: What do you want to get out of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest?

```
scale = [notes[(y+root_i)%len(notes)] for y in [0,2,4,5,7,9,11]]
```

or even

```
scale = [notes[(y+notes.index(root))%len(notes)] for y in [0,2,4,5,7,9,11]]
```

you don't need root_i or index

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is using a `deque`, but there's nothing really wrong with the `list` based approach. I'd just tend to make it a bit more obvious as to what's going on by putting it in its own function...

```
from collections import deque

notes = [ "c", "c#", "d", "d#", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#", "a", "a#", "b" ]

def get_scale(seq, start):
    d = deque(seq)
    d.rotate(-seq.index(start)) 
    yield d[0]
    for idx in [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2]:
        d.rotate(-idx) # always bring element to index 0
        yield d[0] 

print list(get_scale(notes, 'c'))
```

And then, you might as well pre-compute the lot:

```
>>> scales = {k:list(get_scale(notes, k)) for k in notes}
>>> scales
{'a': ['a', 'b', 'c#', 'd', 'e', 'f#', 'g#'], 'c': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'b'], 'b': ['b', 'c#', 'd#', 'e', 'f#', 'g#', 'a#'], 'e': ['e', 'f#', 'g#', 'a', 'b', 'c#', 'd#'], 'd': ['d', 'e', 'f#', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'c#'], 'g': ['g', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f#'], 'f': ['f', 'g', 'a', 'a#', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'c#': ['c#', 'd#', 'f', 'f#', 'g#', 'a#', 'c'], 'd#': ['d#', 'f', 'g', 'g#', 'a#', 'c', 'd'], 'f#': ['f#', 'g#', 'a#', 'b', 'c#', 'd#', 'f'], 'g#': ['g#', 'a#', 'c', 'c#', 'd#', 'f', 'g'], 'a#': ['a#', 'c', 'd', 'd#', 'f', 'g', 'a']}
>>> scales['d']
['d', 'e', 'f#', 'g', 'a', 'b', 'c#']
>>> scales['c']
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you care about getting correct spelling of musical notes, you're going to need a more sophisticated approach.  For instance, your F# major scale will read [F#, G#, A#, B, C#, D#, F], when what you really want is E# for the leading tone.  Similarly, if you care about spelling, you'll need to implement flats as well.  If you care about diatonic scales besides major scales (natural and harmonic minor, Lydian, etc.), you'll also need to decouple the note spacing from the desired scale spacing.  What you'll instead want is something more complex like:

```
def getScale(root='C', mode='major')
    noteNames = ['C','D','E','F','G','A','B']
    noteSpacing = [2,2,1,2,2,2,1]
    if mode == 'natural minor':
        scaleSpacing = [2,1,2,2,1,2,2]
    elif mode == 'harmonic minor':
        scaleSpacing = [2,1,2,2,1,3,1]
    else:
        scaleSpacing = [2,2,1,2,2,2,1]

    startingIndex = noteNames.index(root[0])

    baseSemitoneOffset = root.count('#') - root.count('b')
    currentSemitones = 0
    correctSemitones = 0

    scale = [root]
    for noteDegree in range(1, 7):
        currentIndex = (startingIndex + noteDegree) % len(noteNames)
        currentSemitones += scaleSpacing[(noteDegree -1) % len(noteNames)]
        correctSemitones += noteSpacing[(currentIndex - 1) % len(noteNames)]
        currentSemitonesWithOffset = currentSemitones + baseSemitoneOffset
        thisNoteStep = noteNames[currentIndex]
        if currentSemitonesWithOffset < correctSemitones:
            thisNoteName = thisNoteStep + 'b' * (correctSemitones - currentSemitonesWithOffset)
        elif currentSemitonesWithOffset > correctSemitones:
            thisNoteName = thisNoteStep + '#' * (currentSemitonesWithOffset - correctSemitones)
        else:
            thisNoteName = thisNoteStep
        #print thisNoteName, currentSemitonesWithOffset, currentSemitones, correctSemitones
        scale.append(thisNoteName)

    return scale
```

Which for these values returns what you'd expect

```
print getScale('C')
print getScale('Ab')
print getScale('F#')

['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']
['Ab', 'Bb', 'C', 'Db', 'Eb', 'F', 'G']
['F#', 'G#', 'A#', 'B', 'C#', 'D#', 'E#']
```

And works for more obscure scales:

```
print getScale('C', mode='harmonic minor')
print getScale('Ab', mode='natural minor')
print getScale('Fb', mode='major')

['C', 'D', 'Eb', 'F', 'G', 'Ab', 'B']
['Ab', 'Bb', 'Cb', 'Db', 'Eb', 'Fb', 'Gb']
['Fb', 'Gb', 'Ab', 'Bbb', 'Cb', 'Db', 'Eb']
```

There's a real assumption that music theory is much easier than graphics or audio to implement in a computer...and it is, but not THAT much easier.  Python programmers might be interested in the book [Music for Geeks and Nerds](http://pedrokroger.net/2012/07/music-for-geeks-and-nerds/) by Pedro Kroger; or if you want to get into deeper music theory problems (melodic minor scales, which differ ascending and descending; non-octave repeating scales, etc.) you might (shameless plug for my own work) look at the [music21 Python toolkit](http://web.mit.edu/music21/), especially the [music21.scale](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/html/moduleScale.html) module.

Comment: more than half of what you say is a total mystery to me! What I waned was a simple game-like program to practice my music reading skills... maybe it is because I play the bass and flats are just "the previous note's sharp" in my mind! but then again, my music skills are even worse than my programming ones! ;) +1 for the food for thought.

Comment: LOL.  Well, I hope it's helpful to someone. :-) The more you play, I think, the more you'll want to learn to practice with the standard spelling of scales (where each letter name appears exactly once, perhaps with a sharp or a flat attached). It's like learning French -- at first it's easier to write out "kess coo say" and you'll know exactly how to pronounce "what is it?" but eventually to interact with other speakers and learn new phrases you'll want to make the jump to reading "qu'est-ce que c'est". Enjoy practicing!

Answer (score 1):

```
scale = [notes[i] if i < len(notes) else notes[i-len(notes)] for i in index]
```

can be written as

```
scale = [notes[i % len(notes)] for i in index]
```

The whole can be rewritten using `itertools`:

```
import itertools as it
notes = [ "c", "c#", "d", "d#", "e", "f", "f#", "g", "g#", "a", "a#", "b" ]
major = [2,2,1,2,2,2] # semitone steps
root  = "f"

note_iter = it.dropwhile(root.__ne__, it.cycle(notes))
scale = [list(it.islice(note_iter, m))[0] for m in major]
```

or a "one"-liner:

```
scale = [n for i, n in it.izip(it.chain.from_iterable(xrange(m) for m in major),
                               it.dropwhile(root.__ne__, it.cycle(notes)))
           if i == 0]
```